# How does PostgreSQL cache statements and data?

Tags: postgresql

In Oracle, SQL statements will be cached in shared_pool, and data which is selected frequently will be cached in db_cache.

What does PostgreSQL do? Will SQL statements and data be cached in shared_buffers?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Generally, only the contents of table and index files will be cached in the shared buffer space.

Query plans are cached in some circumstances.  The best way to ensure this is to PREPARE the query once, then EXECUTE it each time.

The results of a query are not automatically cached.  If you rerun the same query -- even if it's letter-for-letter identical, and no updates have been performed on the DB -- it will still execute the whole plan.  It will, of course, make use of any table/index data that's already in the shared buffers cache; so it will not necessarily have to read all the data from disk again.

### Update on plan caching

Plan caching is generally done per session.  This means only the connection that makes the plan can use the cached version.  Other connections have to make and use their own cached versions.  This isn't really a performance issue because the saving you get from reusing a plan is almost always miniscule compared to the cost of connecting anyway.  (Unless your queries are *really* complicated.)

It *does* cache if you use PREPARE: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-prepare.html

It *does* cache when the query is in a PL/plSQL function: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-implementation.html#PLPGSQL-PLAN-CACHING

It *does not* cache ad-hoc queries entered in psql.

Hopefully someone else can elaborate on any other cases of query plan caching.

Comment: Thanks for your explainlation, "Query plans are cached in some circumstances" ,  can you tell more exactly?

Comment: I thought that would come up... I don't know precisely (which is why I was a vague the first time) but I can probably add at least some information on it.

Comment: Thanks ,you give me serveal examples about the plan caching, but I wonder know where are  the cached sql statements and the cached plan located in PostgreSQL ?

Comment: they are cached in the memory heap for the server process handling the connection, which is why you can't observe them from a different connection. The catalog view `pg_prepared_statements` will show the statements for the current connection.

Comment: so are you saying postgres doesn't solve the problem that SQL Server does in that people have created parameterized sql for 10 years now and abandoned stored procs just for that reason, sql server caches that.  So postgres doesn't?  I don't want to be arguing with my DBA about him wanting to use stored procs when I am trying to use things like Knex or even simply dynamic string creation (parameterized sql) on my end in node.  This is typical stuff, I'd think postgres would most certainly inhibit the same benefits SQL Server does

Comment: @MSSucks - It sounds easy to cache ad-hoc query plans like that -- but then every single query has to pay a cost for it.  Not only will numerous plans be kept in a cache and never used again, but every single query string entered needs to be looked up in the cache in case it has already been run before.  Given that an overwhelming number of queries may be one-offs, those costs can easily outweigh the replanning cost for those few ad-hoc queries that are repeated.  Much more efficient to provide the option of explicitly PREPAREing a query that is intended to be rerun often.