# architecture for data analysis

Tags: architecture, etl, data-warehouse, analysis, data-analysis

We have a ERP system which uses PostgreSQL and has some data that my company want to analyse. I have to done what they asked for but I feel my solution is slow. I run SQL queries to fetch data and then beautifully present it on the page. But on every refresh it runs the same code and most of the historical data never changes. I feel their must be some way to make this fast. Like storing the final data in another DB and if the same request is encountered again produce the same result without even thinking(Like cache but more persistent).

I have no experience in this and you guys might have done this things. can I get some pointers  to follow to make the process fast and non-redundant. 
Thanks.

P.S. Just learned about ETL and Data Warehouse. Would these two fit in ? should I go ahead with these or are they too big for this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

You need a query result cache. It looks like the PostgreSQL [does not do it automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7142355/2528649) but there is a [proxy solution](https://code.google.com/p/pqc/) that does it.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you'll use some reporting extension or even a different database more suited for such analytics queries.

If you want to stay within PostgreSQL you may take advance of [materialized views](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Materialized_Views) which allow you to store the results of a view (where a view would be your analysis query).