# MyISAM 'SELECT ... WHERE IN' queries are very slow for ~10M rows table and 100 concurrent connections (each query returns ~50K rows)

Tags: mysql, myisam

I have a MyISAM table with around 10M rows. For a single 'SELECT ... WHERE IN' query (with ~5000 values) it takes ~0.05s to get ~50K rows. However, when performing 100 concurrent similar queries the time rises to ~18s. It makes no sense to me since I have all the indexes in memory and the amount of data returned is not so big in size (~500Kb). Any idea what could be making this so slow? Thank you.

```
CREATE TABLE data (
  A bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL, 
  B int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL, 
  C smallint(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL 
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1; 

ALTER TABLE data ADD KEY A_key (A);
```

The used query:

```
SELECT * FROM data WHERE A IN (VAL1, VAL2, ...);
```

Comment: why is this question upvoted two times without the `show create table [table] statement and the used query.

Comment: downvoted question because the OP left the actual table to our imagination and not giving enough clues to answer.

Comment: Sorry about that. The create table statement:

"CREATE TABLE `data` (`A` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL, `B` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL, `C` smallint(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1; ALTER TABLE `data` ADD KEY `A_key` (`A`);"


The used query:

"SELECT * FROM `data` WHERE `A` IN (VAL1, VAL2, ...);"

Comment: come on man..... that's not how we do things around here.  You're new, so this is all new to you.  Welcome, please put your shoulder into it.   Thanks

Comment: Sorry about that, I tried to create a "pretty comment" but I couldn't... should have edited the main post though, as you did. Any idea related to the question?

Comment: Does your query uses an index on column A. Sometimes MySQL does not use an index, even if one is available? One circumstance under which this occurs is when the optimizer estimates that using the index would require MySQL to access a very large percentage of the rows in the table. (In this case, a table scan is likely to be much faster because it requires fewer seeks.).

Answer (score 0):

You don't say that you're using a stored procedure, so I would start there.  A stored proc is compiled, which means that it should leverage the 'caching' of the query's execution plan.  Since that plan is against in-memory data, you'll get some more performance out of it.

Even though plan-caching [differs from server-to-server](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7142355/263858), you can still leverage a procedure for performance.  E.G. You could make several procedures for your most-common queries.  Albeit: this often requires application/client changes to use those procs.  I have never experimented with having a single proc that checks for query param range(s), and then use a `case` to call one of several static queries.

Answer (score 0):

5000 rows in 50ms is not bad -- probably most of that time is shoveling the data onto the network.

Assuming that is really what the schema looks like, let me explain what is happening *in MyISAM*.  (Not all of this applies to InnoDB, which you should migrate to.)

`INDEX(A)` is manifested in a BTree of pairs: [A, record number].  For each of the 5000 A values, drill down the BTree.  (The BTree will be about 4 levels deep for a 10M-row table.)  The BTree is in 1KB blocks and cached in the key_buffer.  What is the value of `key_buffer_size`?  How much RAM do you have?  What does `SHOW TABLE STATUS` say?  (I want to use those to determine whether the size should be adjusted.)

Once the record number is found, then it does a 'seek' into the .MYD file to find the record, read it (15 bytes), and send it out.  The OS caches these blocks, not MySQL.

That's several thousand potentially cached disk reads.  50ms is enough time to do only about 5 spinning disk reads, so I would say that most, if not all, reads were avoided because of the two caches.

100 concurrent threads...  I assume each is reading 50 rows?  Let me list the bottlenecks:

- 100 vs 1 connections to spin up.
- 100 threads vs 1 contending for the CPU
- 100 threads vs 1 contending for the the key_buffer
- 100 threads vs 1 contending for the OS cache
- 100 threads vs 1 contending for the Query Cache (if you have this turned on; here's a reason to turn it off)
- The last major improvements to MyISAM were back in the days of single-core machines.  Meanwhile, InnoDB has made great strides in properly handline multiple threads.  (Still 100 is beyond the reach of even the latest release.)  (MyISAM has been removed from MySQL 8.0.)